# more filter apply on the DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Good Day!

**Request**
[image]

The following is my raw data, with some conditions applied to check which columns need to be counted.

Example:

- Row 1, direction is export, department code is not starting with 'D',
  will count all 6 columns (ETD, ATD,ETA, ATA, Estimated Delivey,
  Actual Delivery) , and only 5 have been filled in, so get 83 as the
  percentage.
- Row 2, direction is export, department code starting
  with    'D', will only count 4 columns (ETA, ATA,Estimated Delivery
  and    Actual Delivery), and only 2 has been filled in, so get 50%.

**What I have now:**
[image]

I have a code but it only shows all columns and which column has been filled, and I would like some help in calculating the conditions as stated above.

DAX:  (calculate not blank)

```
Count = 
SUMX(
ADDCOLUMNS(
RawData,
"Count",
var tab = {RawData[ETD],RawData[ATD],RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]}
var result = 
COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
tab,
[Value]<>BLANK()))
return
IF(
ISBLANK(result),
0,
result
 ) ),[Count])
```

DAX: Calculate blank

```
Count = 
SUMX(
ADDCOLUMNS(
RawData,
"Count",
var tab = {RawData[ETD],RawData[ATD],RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]}
var result = 
COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
tab,
[Value]=BLANK()))
return
IF(
ISBLANK(result),
0,
result
 ) ),[Count])
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Attached here with my pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIROrAzNEp710JEfxMfiZLzvTpuHj3OZ/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the count I added the decision making of the "D";

```
Count = 
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        RawData,
        "Count",
        var Dep = RawData[Dep]
        var res1 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {RawData[ETD],RawData[ATD],RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]},
                NOT ISBLANK([Value])
            )
        )
        var res2 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]},
                NOT ISBLANK([Value])
            )
        )
        
        return  if (LEFT(Dep, 1) = "D", res1, res2)
    ),
    [Count]
)
```

I also followed your logic to go with the Counts measure:

```
Counts = 
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        RawData,
        "Count",
        var Dep = RawData[Dep]
        var res1 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {RawData[ETD],RawData[ATD],RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]},
                ISBLANK([Value])
            )
        )
        var res2 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {RawData[ETA],RawData[ATA],RawData[Estimated Delivery],RawData[Actual Delivery]},
                ISBLANK([Value])
            )
        )
        
        return  if (LEFT(Dep, 1) = "D", res1, res2)
    ),
    [Count]
)
```

Then I added the measure %

```
% = RawData[Count]/RawData[Total]
```

Result:
[image]

I do believe you would be better of using calculated columns but did not go their as you had choosen measures already.

IF I would have started from scratch, I would have gone with an unpivot table in power query what makes the coding more dynamic

Comment: really appreciate your explanations. Thank you!